# Data type of column in view

Tags: mysql, types, view, casting

I need to replace some legacy table with view. How to specify column types in view?
E.g. old table contains columns `int(10) unsigned`. My view replaces it with `int(11)` and `cast(mycolumn as unsigned)` converts it to `int(11) unsigned`. But old .net-application generates an error during type conversion (I can not modify it to fix this error). 
What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't ever hear there was a way to specify manually data type for view columns in any known DB (oracle, mssql, mysql, postgres). It's calculating automatically based either on data types of real table column which is beeing selected or on some function, e.g. `CAST` like in you case. So the solution may be in using casting.

Comment: I understand, but standard casting in Mysql is not enough flexible to do what I need. May be there is any solution with stored procedure or another way

Answer (score 0):

Define a function with the return type that you need for the column of your view. Calculate the desired value with your function. The type of the view column will be taken as the function return type.

Answer (score 0):

For those of you interested:
I create a "fake" materialized view which is much more fast too load. And then I alter the desired column type.